# Allowing &amp; in CodeIgniter URI

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I'm trying to allow `&amp;` in my Codeigniter URL's. At the moment I'm getting a `Disallowed Key Characters.` error.

I tried extending the Input.php file to allow `&amp;` in the `_clean_input_keys()` function - but it appears it's already too late here as only `amp;` is coming into the provided string.

Does anyone know how I can allow this? Are there any security vulnerabilities that I might be exposing my app to by doing this?

Comment: did you add & in permitted_uri_chars in config.php?

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding `&` and `;`.

Comment: @mcryan were you able to fix this issue, I am also facing a similar issue

Comment: @MahavirMunot I managed to solve it but had to create a bit of a nasty hack. I'll post it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not particularly happy with this answer and welcome a better approach, I had to get this working urgently so I came up with this hack.

I extended `Input.php` and where it loops through the `$_GET` parameters, right before it calls: `$_GET[$this->_clean_input_keys($key)] = $this->_clean_input_data($val);` I added this:

```
if (strpos($key, 'amp;') !== false) {
    $key = str_replace('amp;', '', $key);
}
```

`&` is already removed from the key at this point so I just remove `amp;` before it attempts to clean the data.

Comment: @mycryan I fixed this by setting $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'; in the config/config.php file. The default value is set to "AUTO"